# Script integration Undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, twitch

I have this script :
https://github.com/Fugiman/Twitch-Channel-Status
I want to integrate this in my wordpress site.
But this isn't working . When i debug with console it said :

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

And it highlight this :

```
 document.refreshTwitchChannelStatuses = function () {
    var channels = {};
    // Create a mapping of channel name -> images to update based on that channel's status
    $("img[" + attribute + "]").each(function () {
      var $this = $(this),
          channel = $this.attr(attribute).toLowerCase();

      channels[channel] = channels[channel] || [];
      channels[channel].push($this);

      // If there's no image set already, default to offline
      if (!$this.attr("src")) {
        $this.attr("src", $this.attr("data-offline-image") || offlineImage);
      }
    });
```

Comment: `channels` is an object, the `push` method is not available for `object` but for `array`.

Comment: @R3tep but i use this code on a local wordpress and it work